# Confused about using length value in table field correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, html-table

I am working on a check of data inside one of my tables on page (`form ID = updateformID`).  In the table, I have a checkbox called `holdselectedSched`.

```
<tbody>
     <c:forEach  var="row" items="${Updresults}">
     <c:set var="sched" value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" />
     <c:set var="eftyear" value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" />
     <c:set var="schedcombo"  value="${sched}${eftyear}" />
     <fmt:formatNumber var="schedTotl" value="${row.getTOTAL_AMOUNT()}" pattern="##,###,##0.00"/>
     <tr>
        <td>  
            <input style="width:50px;" type="checkbox" id="holdselectedSched" 
                   name="selectedSched" class="pullchecked"
                   value="<c:out value="${schedcombo}"/>"/>  
       </td>

       <td><c:out value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" /></td>
       <td><c:out value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" /></td>
       <td><c:out value="${row.getCREATION_DATE()}"/></td>
       <td><c:out value="${row.getNUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS()}"/></td>
       <td><c:out value="${schedTotl}"/></td>
     </tr>
     </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

I have the following for loop to go through table and check some fields:

```
 for(var i=0; i<updateformID.holdselectedSched.length; i++)
       {

          var checkSchedule = document.getElementById("checkedTable").rows[i + 1].cells[1] ;
          var checkScheduleSpan = checkSchedule.getElementsByTagName("span") ;
          var checkScheduleSpanDetail = checkScheduleSpan[0].innerHTML;

          var checkYear = document.getElementById("checkedTable").rows[i + 1].cells[2] ;
          var checkYearSpan = checkYear.getElementsByTagName("span") ;
          var checkYearSpanDetail = checkYearSpan[0].innerHTML;

       }
```

When I process this on a table with multiple records, I am getting the correct value in `updateformID.holdselectedSched.length`. But when there is only one record in the table, it is showing up as `undefined`. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library huh? never heard of it. If your length property is zero based, then that would explain why it returns undefined because 0 is not < 0

Comment: try using <= if your length property is zero based

Comment: You have multiple elements with the ID `holdselectedSched`, which is invalid.

Comment: Still don't understand why I was getting the correct value when I did have multiple records in the table.  Probably should just use the count of rows - 1 (remove headers) instead.